# How to create all models with flyway in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have 2 models: `User` and `Product` and 2 sql scripts for create it.

```
Create table 'User'......
Create table 'Product'......
```

I have created the scripts namely `V1__table_users.sql` and `V1__table_products.sql` for each table. But flyway saying it wrong. How do i correctly create entities with flyway?

1. One V1__table_users.sql with all create scripts

   Create table 'User'......
   Create table 'Roles'......
   Create table 'Product'......
2. For each create scrip one sql file but with new version?
   `V1__table_users.sql` 
   `V2__table_products.sql`
   `V3__table_roles.sql` and etc.

3.`V1__table_users.sql` 
`V1__table_products.sql`
`V3__table_roles.sql` and etc.// this way show error

Comment: Please go through flyway script naming conventions https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql

Answer (score 1):

1 or 2 would work, 3 won't as you have seen. Another option would be to create a folder structure such as:

```
v1
- V1.1__create_users.sql
- v1.2__create_roles.sql
- v1.3__create_products.sql 
v2
- V2.1__do_stuff.sql
- V2.2__do_more_stuff.sql
```